How do I make Blender use the system mouse pointer?
Moving from X to Wayland caused all my mouse pointers to double in size. Fixing the system pointers was easy enough, but Blender uses its own custom pointer(s).
Is there a way to make Blender use the system pointers instead of its own? Failing that, is there a way to make it less gigantic?
(If it helps, GIMP seems to use the same pointer, albeit at a reasonable size... so maybe it's a GTK thing? But Inkscape uses the system pointer...)
Curiously, when I first start Blender, the pointer is a reasonable size, but looks "blurry" like it's been subjected to raster resizing (left-most). Once I move it enough to trigger a pointer change, however, it turns enormous (second to left). Second-to-right is how the pointer is configured in System Settings, and what I get in most other programs. Right-most is how it looks in GIMP; also the wrong pointer (and the same wrong pointer), but at least the size is reasonable.





This has more to do with your particular distro and desktop shell than Blender itself. I do not have this problem on Fedora 40 spin KDE Plasma 6 with the official Blender Snap.

@TheLabCat, I'm also on F40, and Blender is using a different pointer than the one that's selected in System Settings, which I see everywhere else. (I'm using the distro package.) AFAIK, code-wise, you have to do something to override the default pointer.

AFAIK Blender uses custom cursors only in specific contexts, I.E. it has a crosshair in the viewport's edit mode. But in most contexts, it should use your system's cursor AFAIK. That being said, though I don't have a lot of experience on Linux, I did notice that depending on the package source of a software, the way it respects your distro's theming (including cursor, but also title bars) can change a lot. So I would look into that if I were you, but this being a linux problematic and not Blender, it would be out of topic to continue about it on Blender Stack Exchange, migrating to Unix Linux.

when you fixed the cursor size in your system settings, did that involve setting "interface scaling"? (or, did you set a display DPI? Can't remember how that works on different desktop environments, to be honest) My suspicion is that you're right, and the whole blender window gets scaled (instead of working at full resolution). Also check Blender's Preferences -> Interface -> Resolution Scale: should be 1.00

ah, and when you open blender, click on the top-left blender Icon-> About Blender, what does it say under "Windowing Environment:"?

(by the way, not quite sure it was wise of the blender SE site to migrate it here. your switching forth-and-back between cursors changing things very strongly indicates this is something caused by blender, or at least blender's interaction with the OS; lots of Linux expertise here, but probably very very little Blender expertise.)

@MarcusMüller, I agree, it is specifically Blender that's behaving badly, at least w.r.t. to size. Also, it's not unusual for apps to have app-specific options to control this sort of thing; I was hoping that would be the case for Blender as well, but evidently it's just broken. Re: scaling, I changed the size from 48 to 24. Yes, I'm using 2x scaling, don't recall what/how DPI is set. The rest of Blender is fine, though; not blurry, text/UI sizes reasonable.

@Lauloque, I'll grant it seems to be sharing pointers with GIMP, so maybe they aren't coming from Blender... but Blender and GIMP don't use the same pointers as Firefox, Inkscape, and all of Qt, which use the cursors I selected in System Settings. The size issue is unique to Blender, however.

Check out Cursor themes. It is a page on Arch wiki, but distro-specific parts mostly have to do with package management and AUR.

@Matthew I bet that 2× scaling just pixel-scales X11 apps in the X "container" windows on wayland.
